# Git push error after pull --rebase

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I rebased changes from a remote repo `upstream master` into my local `dev` branch and then tried pushing the changes to my repo using these commands:

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
git push origin dev
```

but the later command resulted into that error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/m-adil/some_repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

This is what that I'm facing for the third time but didn't come across with a perfect solution yet. Doing `git pull ...` as suggested in second last line of error, results in producing all the conflicts again that ruins the recent `git pull --rebase ...`. In such cases `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` remediates but what is the best approach in this case to push your changes?

I explored this and found several similar questions here but with some minute distinctions that don't clarify this issue to me. Most of the [selected answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762355/3151337) suggests to do `git push --force origin my_branch` but it has cons as well and one can lose his changes in remote so this can't be suggested. 
The best thing I came to know yet is to [create & checkout to a new branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827930/how-do-i-resolve-a-github-message-that-says-the-tip-of-my-current-branch-is-behi#comment20809335_14828023) which is better than many other answers/solutions. But this is more like a trick to escape from this issues rather than a right approach to deal with that situation. So can any body please clarify by sharing the right approach in this case?

Comment: Why did you rebase `upstream/master`?  This rewrites your local history in a way that is incompatible with `origin/master`, which is why you're seeing errors.  You should only `pull --rebase` when you're sure that it won't cause such historical conflicts (e.g., when there's only one remote).

Comment: What branch were you actually on when doing these commands?  Do you really have the same branch across two different remotes?

Comment: @WillVousden Sorry I didn't get exactly what you mean, can you please explain it bit more? I'm working with a remote repo i.e. upstream master. My coworker did some changes in his repo (upstream repo) and I wanna rebase his changes with my local repo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is that necessary to be on a same named repo? That could be the issue if so. I'm working on `dev` branch and want to rebase changes from `upstream master`

Comment: I had deleted an earlier comment which basically said that if you rebased a local `master` branch on the remote `master` and then pushed to the same remote, you should _not_ be getting these errors.  There isn't anything wrong with using rebase in this way AFAIK.  Update your question with what you are really doing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please give it a look now, I updated fist line of my question, hopefully that would be clear now.

Comment: Last question: Is the `dev` branch public or shared by anyone other than yourself?

Comment: Nope its private and just me alone is working on `dev` branch

Answer (score 4):

Since your `dev` branch is private and you are the only one using it at the moment, then there is nothing inherently wrong with rewriting its history and then doing a force push.  As you noted, the way to get around the error you are getting is to force push to the remote, e.g.

```
git push --force origin dev
```

This would overwrite the remote `dev` branch with what you had locally.  But since no one else can see this other than yourself, it should be safe to do.

By way of diagrams, consider that `dev` starts off on the remote with one additional commit beyond what `master` has:

```
master: ... A -- B -- C
                       \
dev:                    D
```

Now, someone else has done some work in `master`, and pushed that work.  Let's say it's just a single commit, leaving us with this:

```
master: ... A -- B -- C -- E
                       \
dev:                    D
```

Locally, you did a rebase of `dev` on `master`, which gives us the following branches (note that one `dev` is marked as local):

```
master:    ... A -- B -- C -- E
                          \    \
dev:                       D    \
                                 \
local-dev:                        D'
```

But now, when you try to push `local-dev` to the remote `dev`, Git gets confused.  It is confused because what is has remotely is the `D` commit on top of `C`.  But your local branch, which you are trying to push, has commits `E--D'` on top of `C`.  It can't resolve this automatically, so it fails.  Doing the force push gets around this, which in your situation should be an acceptable thing to do.